# SQL Server - tsql join/filtering issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Probably the wrong title, but I can't summarise what I'm trying to do nicely. Which is probably why my googling hasn't helped.

I have a list of `Discounts`, and a list of `TeamExclusiveDiscounts` (`DiscountId, TeamId`)

I call a stored procedure passing in `@TeamID (int)`.

What I want is all `Discounts` except if they're in `TeamExclusiveDiscounts` and don't have `TeamID` matching `@TeamId`.

So the data is something like

Table `Discount`:

```
DiscountID     Name
-----------------------
1              Test 1
2              Test 2
3              Test 3
4              Test 4
5              Test 5
```

Table `TeamExclusiveDiscount`:

```
DiscountID     TeamID
-----------------------
1              10
2              10
2              4
3              8
```

Expected results:

- searching for `TeamID = 10` I should get discounts 1,2,4,5
- searching for `TeamID = 5` I should get discounts 4, 5
- searching for `TeamID = 8` I should get discounts 3, 4, 5

I've tried a variety of joins, or trying to update a temp table to set whether the discount is allowed or not, but I just can't seem to get my head around this issue.

So I'm after the T-SQL for my stored procedure that will select the correct discounts (SQL Server). Thanks!

Comment: Next time add the code you have struggled with.

Comment: I didn't bother @Horaciux as it was just a mess of jumbled sql, and I didn't feel I was even close. Usually I would though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT D.DiscountID FROM Discounts D
   LEFT JOIN TeamExclusiveDiscount T
     ON D.DiscountID=T.DiscountID
WHERE T.TeamID=@TeamID OR T.TeamID IS NULL
```

[SQLFIDDLE for TEST](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5beff/14)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this - it only selects records where there is a teamdiscount record with the team or no teamdiscount record at all.

```
SELECT * FROM Discounts D
WHERE 
EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM TeamExclusiveDiscount T 
    WHERE T.DiscountID = D.DiscountID
    AND TeamID = @TeamID
)
OR
NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM TeamExclusiveDiscount T 
    WHERE T.DiscountID = D.DiscountID
)
```

Comment: Thanks this does work, but will go with a "join" answer as it's more succint.  Appreciate the effort though :)

Comment: Thats OK. Just be aware the join will 'double count' if there are duplicates in TeamExclusiveDiscount. But if you have a unique constraint on DiscountID/TeamID that won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I like to translate the English description directly into SQL (atleast as a first pass): 
"All Discounts except if they're in TeamExclusiveDiscounts and don't have TeamID matching @TeamId."

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM Discounts D   -- All Discounts
  WHERE D.DiscountID NOT IN   -- except if they're in TeamExclusiveDiscounts 
        (SELECT T.DiscountID
        FROM TeamExclusiveDiscount T 
        WHERE T.DiscountID NOT IN   -- and don't have TeamID matching @TeamId. 
            (SELECT Match.DiscountID
             FROM TeamExclusiveDiscount Match 
             WHERE Match.TeamID = @TeamID)
         )
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  This does work, and I do need to get better at translating my english into sql as you suggested :)